# Reading char array containing Hex values in C

Tags: c, arrays, hex

This is part of a program that I use to decrypt AES in C. The program is supposed to take in an IV from an external file, read it then set as the IV. Unfortunately the IV is declared as a char array in the code (which I cannot change) so what I tried to do is to read the external file as byte[], then convert it to char[].

One of the issues I am currently facing is regarding the AES_IV variable as seen below:

```
#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE  0x10

char AES_IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88,0x99,0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD,0xEE,0xFF};
```

When I try to print out the AES_IV using the code

```
printf("\nAES_IV: ");
for (i3 = 0; i3 < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i3++) {
printf("%02x", AES_IV[i3]);
}
printf("\n");
```

The output is:

```
AES_IV: 0c0a513398f1eda13ed2fc7213b50b10
```

Which is different from the AES_IV I declared.

I changed the for loop to

```
for (i3 = 0; i3 < 50; i3++) {
```

and the resultant output is much longer

```
AES_IV: 0c0a513398f1eda13ed2fc7213b50b105369a...(100 chars in total)
```

I checked the length of AES_IV and it is still 16, but **why does my for loop returns such a long result? Also why did the value of AES_IV change?** I have checked and there are no reference to AES_IV anywhere before this part.

Your help is much appreciated.

Source code for reference:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "SmartSDLib.h"

#define SDCARD_PATH "/boot"

#define P1_INDEX 2
#define P2_INDEX 3
#define P3_INDEX 4

#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE  0x10
#define APDU_HEADER_SIZE 5

#define FILELEN 32 // For reading IV from file

void To_Hex(char s8Data[],char hexBuffer[], int offset, int nlen)
{
    int j;
    int nSize = (nlen - offset); 
    char finalhash[8192];
    char hexval [] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

    for(j=0 ; j < nSize; j++)
    {
        finalhash[j*2] = hexval[(s8Data[j] >> 4) & 0xF];
        finalhash[(j*2) + 1] = hexval[s8Data[j] & 0x0F];
    }

    memset(hexBuffer,0x00,8192);
    memcpy(hexBuffer, finalhash, nSize*2);
}

char * AccessAPDU(char command[], int size)
{
    unsigned char u8Ret;
    int s32Len[1];
    char s8Buffer[512], hexBuffer[8192];

    To_Hex(command, hexBuffer, 0, size);
    //printf ("%s\n%s%s\n", "AccessAPDUCommand:","CMD:" , hexBuffer);
    u8Ret = OT_SmartSDCard_AccessAPDUCommand(size, command, s32Len, s8Buffer, 0);
    if(u8Ret == 0x00)
    {
        printResult(s32Len, s8Buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("%s%x\n\n", "Error 0x", u8Ret);
    }
    return s8Buffer;
}

void printResult (int s32Len[], char s8Buffer[])
{
    char hexBuffer[8192];
    if(s32Len[0] >= 2)
    {
        To_Hex(s8Buffer, hexBuffer, 0, s32Len[0]);
    //  printf ("%s%s\n", "Ret:", hexBuffer);
    //  printf ("%s%d\n\n", "Len: ", s32Len[0]);
    } 
    else
    {
        printf ("%s%d\n", "Len: ", s32Len[0]);
    }
}

void CopyBuffer(char Dest[], char Source[], unsigned int length){
    while(length){
        Dest[length - 1] = Source[length - 1];
        length--;
    }
}

int ascii_to_hex(char c) // For reading IV from file
{
        int num = (int) c;
        if(num < 58 && num > 47) // Handle numbers (0-9)
        {
                return num - 48;
        }
        if(num < 103 && num > 96) // Handle lowercase alphabets (a-f)
        {
                return num - 87;
        }
        if(num < 71 && num > 64) // Handle uppercase alphabets (A-F)
        {
                return num - 55;
        }
        return num;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char u8Ret;    
    char SDCard_Path[64];
    char line[64];
    int s32Len[1];
    char s8Buffer[512], hexBuffer[8192];
    int exit = 1;
    int iChoice;
    char * response;
    int test;
    char testchar[32];
    bool flag = true;

    char fileName[100];
    char encrypted[100];
    char decrypted[100];
    int i;
    int j;
    int blockCounter = 0;
    int commandCounter = 0;
    char imageBuffer[1];

    /* APDU commands */
    char AES_encrypt_cmd[APDU_HEADER_SIZE + AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0x80, 0x2A, 0x01,0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE}; //encryption APDU
    char AES_decrypt_cmd[APDU_HEADER_SIZE + AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0x80, 0x2A, 0x02,0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE}; //decryption APDU
    char GetResponse_cmd[]                                  = {0x00, 0xC0, 0x00,0x00, 0x00}; //Le to be changed before use
    char SelectAESapplet_cmd[]                              = {0x00, 0xA4, 0x04,0x00, 0x10, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x77, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04};
    //char PutKeyAES_cmd[]                                    = {0x80, 0xD8, 0x00,0xF8, 0x20, 0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88,0x99,0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD,0xEE,0xFF,0xFF,0xEE,0xDD,0xCC,0xBB,0xAA,0x99,0x88,0x77,0x66,0x55,0x44,0x33,0x22,0x11,0x00};
    char PutKeyAES_cmd[]                                    = {0x80, 0xD8, 0x00,0xF8, 0x20, 0xCF,0x10,0xF9,0xBD,0xF6,0xAA,0x15,0xC5,0x0E,0xCD,0x79,0xE6,0x28,0x3D,0xA8,0x0A,0x79,0x7A,0x2D,0x27,0x03,0xAE,0x07,0xD5,0x2F,0x5D,0x8F,0x60,0x1F,0x1E,0xF2,0x6F};

    /* AES variables */
    int  AES_keyIndex = 0;
    char AES_IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88,0x99,0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD,0xEE,0xFF};
    //char AES_IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0x12,0xFB,0x87,0x11,0x62,0x7E,0xBB,0x55,0x71,0x7B,0x2F,0x70,0xA4,0x97,0x55,0x7B};
    //char AES_IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    char AES_CBC_vector[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    char AES_cmdBuffer[APDU_HEADER_SIZE + AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

    FILE * rFile;
    FILE * wFile;

    FILE *fileptr;char *buffer;long filelen;int i2,i3,i4;char IV_temp[AES_BLOCK_SIZE]; // This line for the file --> byte --> Hex


    printf ("%s\n", "This program will run 1, 2 followed by 6");


    //      case 1 :
                printf ("%s\n", "Initializing: ");
                u8Ret = OT_SmartSDCard_Initialization(SDCARD_PATH);
                if(u8Ret == 0x00)
                    printf ("%s\n\n", "Initialization OK");
                else
                    printf ("%s%x\n\n", "Initialization: Error 0x",u8Ret);

            //  printf ("%s\n\n", "-------------------------------------");

                /* ATR */
                u8Ret = OT_SmartSDCard_Reset(s32Len, s8Buffer);
                if(u8Ret == 0x00)
                {
                    To_Hex(s8Buffer,hexBuffer, 0, s32Len[0]);
          //          printf ("%s%s\n", "ATR : ", hexBuffer);
          //          printf ("%s%d\n\n", "Len : ", s32Len[0]);
                }
                else
                    printf ("%s%x\n\n", "Reset: Error 0x",u8Ret);
          //      printf ("%s\n\n", "-------------------------------------");

                /* Select AES applet */
                printf("%s\n", "Selecting AES applet...");
                response = AccessAPDU(SelectAESapplet_cmd, sizeof(SelectAESapplet_cmd));
                if(response[0] == 0x61){
                    GetResponse_cmd[P3_INDEX] = response[1];
                    AccessAPDU(GetResponse_cmd, sizeof(GetResponse_cmd));
                }
          //      printf ("%s\n\n", "-------------------------------------");


    //      case 2 :
                printf("Putting key...");

                AES_keyIndex = 0;
                memset(line, 0x00, sizeof(line));

                PutKeyAES_cmd[2] = AES_keyIndex;
                printf("putting key on index %d\n", AES_keyIndex);
                response = AccessAPDU(PutKeyAES_cmd, sizeof(PutKeyAES_cmd));

                AES_encrypt_cmd[P2_INDEX] = AES_keyIndex;
                AES_decrypt_cmd[P2_INDEX] = AES_keyIndex;

            //  printf ("%s\n\n", "-------------------------------------");


    //      case 6 :
                printf ("Decrypting in CBC...");
            //  printf ("File Name: /home/pi/test_encrypted\n");
            //    printf ("Encrypted File Name: /home/pi/test_decrypted\n");
                rFile = fopen("/home/pi/test_encrypted","rb");
                wFile = fopen("/home/pi/test_decrypted","wb");

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // This part to read rFile and store as a byte [WORKING!]

                fseek(rFile, 0, SEEK_END);          // Jump to the end of the file
                filelen = ftell(rFile);             // Get the current byte offset in the file
                rewind(rFile);                      // Jump back to the beginning of the file

                buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen+1)*sizeof(char)); // Enough memory for file + \0
                fread(buffer, filelen, 1, rFile); // Read in the entire file

                // This part to convert buffer to hex value [WORKING!]

                for (i2 = 0; i2 < 100; i2++)
                {
                    if (i2 > 0) printf(" ");
                    printf("%02X", buffer[i2]);
                    IV_temp[i2] = buffer[i2];
                }

                // This part to print stuff [AES_IV not printing out correctly]

                printf("\nAES_IV: ");
                //fwrite(AES_IV, 1, sizeof(AES_IV), stdout);
                for (i3 = 0; i3 < 50; i3++) {
                    printf("%02x", AES_IV[i3]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                /*
                printf("IV_temp: ");
                for (i4 = 0; i4 < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i4++) {
                    printf("%02x", IV_temp[i4]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                */
                for (i3 = 0; i3 < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i3++) {
                    AES_IV[i3] = IV_temp[i3];
                }
                printf("\nLength of AES_IV = %d\n", sizeof(AES_IV));
                printf("\nAES_IV: ");

                for (i3 = 0; i3 < 50; i3++) {
                    printf("%02x", AES_IV[i3]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                // Return the file pointer to start of file
                rewind(rFile);
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                if (rFile == NULL || wFile == NULL)
                    perror("Error opening File");
                else{
                    int IsEOF = false;
                    // Initialize the CBC block with IV
                    CopyBuffer(AES_CBC_vector, AES_IV, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

                    while (IsEOF == false) {
                        i = 0;
                        while(i < AES_BLOCK_SIZE){ // i run from 0 to (AES_BLOCK_SIZE - 1)
                            AES_cmdBuffer[APDU_HEADER_SIZE + i] = fgetc(rFile);
                            if(feof(rFile)) {
                                IsEOF = true;
                                if(i == 0) { // break out of while loop if a new block is not yet in progress
                                    break;
                                } else { // continue to finish the block and pad with zeros
                                    AES_cmdBuffer[APDU_HEADER_SIZE + i] = 0x00; //padding
                                }
                            }

                            i++;
                        }

                        if(i == 0) break; //break out of while loop, nothing to send to card

                        // Fill in the APDU header
                        CopyBuffer(AES_cmdBuffer, AES_decrypt_cmd, APDU_HEADER_SIZE);

                        response = AccessAPDU(AES_cmdBuffer, sizeof(AES_cmdBuffer));

                        if(response[0] == 0x61){
                            if(response[1] != AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
                                perror("Card returning wrong block size");
                            }

                            GetResponse_cmd[P3_INDEX] = AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
                            response = AccessAPDU(GetResponse_cmd, sizeof(GetResponse_cmd));

                            /* CBC mode */
                            for(i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i++){
                                response[i] ^= AES_CBC_vector[i];
                            }

                            fwrite(response, sizeof(char), AES_BLOCK_SIZE, wFile);

                            // Take the ciphertext to perform XOR next time
                            CopyBuffer(AES_CBC_vector, &AES_cmdBuffer[APDU_HEADER_SIZE], AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
                        } else {
                            perror("Error decrypting file using the smart card");
                        }
                    }
                }
                fclose (rFile);
                fclose (wFile);
            //  printf ("%s\n\n", "-------------------------------------");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char AES_IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE]` --> `unsigned char AES_IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE]`

Comment: I really doubt you can compile such a code. Full of implicit declarations and overflows of types...

Comment: "why does my for loop returns such a long result?" because you tell him to do so: `for (i3 = 0; i3 < 50; i3++)` will loop from 0 to 49 so fifty iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out the issue is with the previous for loop (runs 100 iterations) which overwrites the value of AES_IV, so changing the iteration count to sizeof(buffer) fixed the issue. No changing of the type required.

Answer (score 1):

As one comment already stated you should use `unsigned char` otherwise each element is treated as a `signed char` by default. Better yet you might want to use fixed-width `uint8_t` from `#include <stdint.h>` instead.

Here is a minimal example that works as expected:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE  0x10

uint8_t AES_IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88,0x99,0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD,0xEE,0xFF};

int
main( void )
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(AES_IV); i++ ) {
        printf( "%02x", AES_IV[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```